# Display a part of image using binary data

Tags: php, image-processing, data-uri

I wonder if it is possible to display a part of image using `file_get_contents`.

Currently I'm using this code to display the image without revealing its link/location

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,<?php echo base64_encode(file_get_contents($image)); ?> ">
```

Is there a way to just display 1/3 or 1/2 of the image using `file_get_contents`?

Answer (score 2):

To do this, you need to decode, crop and re-encode the image.  In PHP, you can use the [GD library](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) to do this, e.g.:

```php
# load source image and get its size
$img = imagecreatefromgif( $image_file_name );
$width = imagesx( $img );
$height = imagesy( $img );

# create a copy showing only the top half of the image
$cropped = imagecreate( $width, $height / 2 );
imagecopy( $cropped, $img, 0,0, 0,0, $width, $height/2 );

# output image in GIF format emdebbed on the page
# XXX: GD doesn't seem to support output to string directly, but we can hack it
ob_start(); imagegif( $cropped ); $gif = ob_get_clean();
echo '<img src="data:image/gif;base64,', base64_encode( $gif ), '">';

# free the image objects once they're no longer needed
imagedestroy( $img );
imagedestroy( $cropped );
```

Comment: @Susan: Why would you edit that? `echo` can [output multiple strings separated by commas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466408/difference-between-and-in-php) just fine, and [it's even slightly more efficient](http://www.fusionswift.com/2010/05/php-concatenation-benchmark-comma-vs-period/) than concatenating the parameters into a single string first. (Thanks for the upvote, though!)

Comment: My bad..If I remember correctly I thought in my tests that it was erroring out, but just tested again and (as expected) it works a-ok. Must have been barking up the wrong tree at the time.

Answer (score 1):

The browser will not decode partial images. You can use various CSS techniques to hide the remaining areas of the image, such as wrapping your image in a DIV, setting CSS width + height with `overflow:hidden`, or setting it as a CSS background and setting the dimensions of that element.

Alternately, you can render it in `canvas`.

Comment: I want to hide the image's content so css technique will not work. I guess I can either use some sort of php library to crop the image in binary, or make an another cropped image file.

Comment: Anyone can sniff the data uri on the client and grab the image, regardless of what client-side technique you use. The only way to truly hide things is not to deliver them to the client.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear enough. The image is to display to registered member. What I'm trying to archive is to display a part of the image to non-registered member. I don't mind if they grab the image, I just don't want them to be able to track the location of the image's folder.

Comment: A data uri is good for that. Or you can proxy the image through a program <img src="sonething.php?image=12345"> which will send out a MIME header for the image, then stream the data, thus masking the source.