# Why doesn't the html br break line tag doesn't work in this code?

Tags: php, html, operator-precedence

Can some one tell why my php line break not working ( echoing ) ?

I know i can write the code in a different way to make the line break work, but i want to know the reason behind this ?

```
<?php

    $var1 = 3;

    echo "Addition = "       . $var1 += 3 . "<br>";
    echo "Subtraction = "    . $var1 -= 3 . "<br>";
    echo "Multiplication = " . $var1 *= 3 . "<br>";
    echo "Division = "       . $var1 /= 3 . "<br>";

?>
```

Comment: in command line or web ? i mean is it a console app ?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Try to be more specific.

Comment: If you are using CLI try '\r\n' otherwise in web <br/> should work

Comment: Read up in operator precedence.(Seems like a war area for vampires.)

Comment: So do we make any progress here with this question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use commas,

```
echo "Addition = " . $var1 += 3 , "<br>";
echo "Subtraction = " . $var1 -= 3 ,"<br>";
echo "Addition = " . $var1 *= 3 , "<br>";
echo "Addition = " . $var1 /= 3 ,"<br>";
```

Or wrap it in brackets:

```
echo "Addition = " . ($var1 += 3) . "<br>";
echo "Subtraction = " . ($var1 -= 3) ."<br>";
echo "Addition = " . ($var1 *= 3) . "<br>";
echo "Addition = " . ($var1 /= 3) ."<br>";
```

Otherwise the `3` number is concatenated with `<br>`.

Comment: Interesting, but lacks any form of explanation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466408/difference-between-and-in-php

Answer (score 8):

Well seems like I have to clean some things up here.

Let's take a look at the [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php), which says:

1. `.` has a higher precedence, than `+=`, `-=`, `*=`, `/=`
2. `.` is left associative
3. `=`, `+=`, `-=`, `*=`, `/=` is right associative
4. We also take a look at the note at the bottom of the manual:

   > **Note:**
   > Although **= has a lower precedence than most other operators, PHP will still allow expressions similar to the following: if (!$a = foo())**, in which case the return value of foo() is put into $a.

Means that even tough `=` has a lower precedence than `.` it gets evaluated first. You can also see this if you do something like this:

```
$xy = "HERE";
echo "I am " . $xy = "NOT HERE";
```

Now you would think that `.` has a higher precedence than `=` and will get evaluated first, but as from the note in the manual, the assignment is first and you end up with this:

```
echo "I am " . ($xy = "NOT HERE");
```

output:

```
I am NOT HERE
```

So if we put all these information's together, we can say, that the assignment gets evaluated first, but it's right assocative. Means this:

```
$var1 = 3;

echo "Addition = "    . ($var1 += 3 . "<br>");
echo "Subtraction = " . ($var1 -= 3 . "<br>");
echo "Addition = "    . ($var1 *= 3 . "<br>");
echo "Addition = "    . ($var1 /= 3 . "<br>");
```

So this code will end up in this:

```
echo "Addition = "    . ($var1 += "3<br>");
echo "Subtraction = " . ($var1 -= "3<br>");
echo "Addition = "    . ($var1 *= "3<br>");
echo "Addition = "    . ($var1 /= "3<br>");
```

Which then through the arithmetic operator gets [convert to an integer](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion) we end up with this:

```
echo "Addition = "    . ($var1 += 3);
echo "Subtraction = " . ($var1 -= 3);
echo "Addition = "    . ($var1 *= 3);
echo "Addition = "    . ($var1 /= 3);
```

And after the assignment is done the concatenation gets evaluated, which looks like this:

```
echo "Addition = "    . 6;
echo "Subtraction = " . 3;
echo "Addition = "    . 9;
echo "Addition = "    . 3;
```

With this you end up in this output:

```
Addition = 6Subtraction = 3Addition = 9Addition = 3
```

And now how to solve this? Simply wrap your assignment in parentheses, so that the `<br>` tag doesn't get into the assignment. E.g.

```
echo "Addition = "       . ($var1 += 3) . "<br>";
echo "Subtraction = "    . ($var1 -= 3) . "<br>";
echo "Multiplication = " . ($var1 *= 3) . "<br>";
echo "Division = "       . ($var1 /= 3) . "<br>";
                         //^          ^ So the br tag doesn't get in the assignment of the variable.
```

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to contain false information like some of the others and clarifies what happens and why. +1

Comment: @Peter Thanks, yes I though I break everything in single steps to show what happens.

Comment: This is what we call a perfect answer.. +1

Comment: @Uchiha Thanks I tried to make everything as clear as possible.

Answer (score 4):

This is happening because of the type casting issues. `3 . "<br>"` will be converted to number while the operation will be performed. Wrap the inside `()` so that the operations are performed first then the concatenation.

```
echo "Addition = " . ($var1 += 3) . "<br>";
echo "Subtraction = " . ($var1 -= 3) ."<br>";
echo "Addition = " . ($var1 *= 3) . "<br>";
echo "Addition = " . ($var1 /= 3) ."<br>";
```

Comment: What difference between my answer and yours?

Comment: @Deena Why should OP try your answer? What is the issue?

Comment: @Deena might be an explanation

Comment: @Uchiha you are right.

Answer (score 3):

Your PHP means:

```
echo "Addition = " . $var1 += (3 . "<br>");
echo "Subtraction = " . $var1 -= (3 ."<br>");
echo "Addition = " . $var1 *= (3 . "<br>");
echo "Addition = " . $var1 /= (3 ."<br>");
```

And `number + 3 . '<br>'` is `number + (int)(3 . '<br>')` which is `number + 3`. No `<br>` exists now due to retyping to number(converting to number).

Use brackets around equations.

```
echo "Addition = " . ($var1 += 3) . "<br>";
echo "Subtraction = " . ($var1 -= 3) ."<br>";
echo "Addition = " . ($var1 *= 3) . "<br>";
echo "Addition = " . ($var1 /= 3) ."<br>";
```

Comment: The concatenation dot is left associative! NOT right!

Comment: @Rizier123: are you sure? It works me well as I wrote above. Or... is there another reason why the behavior is as I wrote? You can insert own answer if you know st. more.

Comment: From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) : **left** `* / % arithmetic`

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

"." is used for php variable to concate not for numbers

```
<?php


$var1 = 3;

echo "Addition = ". ($var1 += 3) ."</br>";
echo "Subtraction = ". ($var1 -= 3) ."</br>";
echo "Addition = ". ($var1 *= 3) ."</br>";
echo "Addition = ". ($var1 /= 3) ."</br>";

?>
```

Comment: Sorry, but that explanation above the code is total nonsense.

Comment: ok can you explain this

Comment: The dot operator concatenates whatever string operands it is given, regardless whether it is variables or literals or language constructs. Numeric values would get interpreted as strings too by conversion. Out of interest: where is that statement from that the dot operator "is only" for variables?

Comment: Yours also work but need some explanation Mate@Deena.Your explanation doesn't ,make any sense why OPs code is not working

Answer (score 1):

Try this way.

```
 <?php
$var1 = 3;

echo "Addition =" . ($var1 += 3 ).'<br>';
echo "Subtraction =" . ($var1 -= 3).'<br>';
echo "Addition =" . ($var1 *= 3 ).'<br>';
echo "Addition =" . ($var1 /= 3 ).'<br>';

?>
```

Comment: Extremely complicated change to achieve only a minor difference. Why?