# Why i am getting error in this Addition and subtraction in PHP5.6.8

Tags: php

I am using PHP 5.6.8 Version in xampp server. In that i am getting error in output in output the addition and sub time i got this output for this code

```
    <? 
echo"Hello PHP"."&nbsp;". "Whats up"."<br/>";
echo "ADDING". 2+2 ."<br/>";
echo "SUB".3-2 ."<br/>";
echo "MUL". 2*2 ."<br/>";
echo "DIV". 2/2 ."<br/>";
echo "MODULS". 5%2 ."<br/>";
?>
```

Output

```
Hello PHP Whats up
2
-2
MUL4
DIV1
MODULS1
```

Comment: Welcome to PHP [type juggling](https://php.net/manual/ro/language.types.type-juggling.php). You need to specifically delimit mathematical operation from concatenation(it's good practice to delimit them generally). Since concatenation has, stupidly enough, a higher priority than some mathematical operations. Long story short: `echo "ADDING". (2+2) ."<br/>";` - notice the brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using **,(comma)** instead of **.(dot)**. As its all because of [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) and for how precedence operator work there's a answer within [Why doesn't the html br break line tag doesn't work in this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30435441/why-doesnt-the-html-br-break-line-tag-doesnt-work-in-this-code) answered by Rizier123

```
echo"Hello PHP"."&nbsp;". "Whats up"."<br/>";
echo "ADDING", 2+2 ,"<br/>";
echo "SUB", 3-2 ,"<br/>";
echo "MUL", 2*2 ,"<br/>";
echo "DIV", 2/2 ,"<br/>";
echo "MODULS", 5%2 ,"<br/>";
```

Answer (score 0):

`2+2 ."<br/>"` will be treated as `2 + (2 . "<br/>")` which is not correct.

Add `()` -

```
echo "ADDING". (2+2) ."<br/>";
echo "SUB". (3-2) ."<br/>";
echo "MUL". (2*2) ."<br/>";
echo "DIV". (2/2) ."<br/>";
echo "MODULS". (5%2) ."<br/>";
```

There is no space between `.` and `3` on `echo "SUB".3-2 ."<br/>";`. That is the reason it is giving error for that line and others are working.

Comment: Issue was with the space. Updated the answer.