# Which is the correct way of using core predefined constant PHP_EOL inside a double quoted string and single quoted string?

Tags: php, string, syntax, constants, eol

Consider below code example making use of `PHP_EOL` :

```
<?php

  $juices = array("apple", "orange", "koolaid1" => "purple");
  class people {
    public $john = "John Smith";
  }

  $string = 'string';
  $people = new people();

  //In below statement dot(.) is used before PHP_EOL
  echo "$people->john drank some $juices[0] juice.".PHP_EOL;

  //In below statement comma(,) is used before PHP_EOL
  echo "The character at index -2 is $string[-2].", PHP_EOL;

?>
```

Output :

```
John Smith drank some apple juice. 
The character at index -2 is n.
```

If you look at the above code closely, especially at the lines making use of `PHP_EOL`, you will come to know the difference in the preceding character to `PHP_EOL` in both statements.

In first statement `PHP_EOL` is preceded by a dot(.) whereas in second statement it is preceded by a comma(,)

Why such difference is there in the syntax as both the statements are generating the same output only?

Someone please clear the confusion.

**Note :** I know that core predefined constant `PHP_EOL` is used to put the correct 'End Of Line' symbol for the platform on which program is executing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between period and comma when concatenating with echo versus return?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1466429/5914775)

Comment: Most of your code is pointless when trying to show a minimal example of your problem/question.  All of the strings/classes do nothing to make your point clear - IMHO.

Comment: I also don't see where in your example you have single quoted strings as    listed in your title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo "$people->john drank some $juices[0] juice.".PHP_EOL;
```

Here `.(dot)` works like it will first concatenate the total string then prints.

But comes to `,`

```
echo "The character at index -2 is $string[-2].", PHP_EOL;
```

it won't concatenate. it will print one after other based on `,`