# What do parentheses around a variable do in PHP?

Tags: php, variables, parentheses

I am using ImageMagick in PHP 5.3 on an old platform. I stumbled upon a piece of code which was not working when parentheses were used around a variable, but did work when these parentheses were removed. What do parentheses around a variable do?

```
$im = new imagick();
$im->readImageBlob($photo);
$im->setImageFormat('jpg');
$photo = ($im);
```

It did not read the image data with this code, but it did when I removed the parentheses.

```
$photo = $im;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: There's something else going on, those two lines are absolutely identical

Answer (score 5):

Parentheses around a variable are just for precedence and usually used in calculations. With the code you're showing, there's absolutely no functional difference between `$photo = $im;` and `$photo = ($im);`

For example:

```
$x = 2;
$y = 5;
$z = 10;
$result_1 = $x * $y + $z; //might not give you the result you expect.
$result_2 = $x * ($y + $z); //This will ensure that $y & $z get added before multiplying by $x.
```

The above is what parentheses are normally used for.

Comment: I understand, but there is a difference in result in my code, so there must be a difference

Comment: Is there an error in the log? Chances are, the problem isn't really the parentheses even though it might look like that on the surface. PHP would simply ignore it if there's nothing else for it to act on other than the one variable.